# Query, while creating a jar?

Tags: eclipse, jar

> Resource is out of sync with the file system

This the error that is thrown out while creating a jar in eclipse IDE...

What does this mean? And how to rectify it?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming this is while you're using Eclipse...

I suspect that it means you've changed a file on the file system but the Eclipse workspace is still "looking at" the old version. Hitting Refresh (F5) on either the file or the whole project would usually sort it out. If you're seeing it *every* time you create a jar file, that suggests your project is *looking at* your build output, which isn't ideal.

Comment: How do you make your project stop looking at your build output in Eclipse?

Comment: @rotaercz: Don't have one of your *output* paths also configured as an *input* path...

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse caches file content to make things go faster.

It has detected that the version on disk has changed since it was put in the cache, and you need to refresh the workspace to update the cached version.

This typically happen when you fiddle with files outside of Eclipse.  If the process doing the fiddling is invoked from within Eclipse you can tell Eclipse to refresh the workspace when the process is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse keeps metadata about all files within every eclipse project. "Resource is out of sync with the file system..." means that eclipse has noticed that a file has been changed (or deleted) from outside eclipse. Refreshing the project in question (from the context menu in the package explorer) should fix the problem.